# <hr> property doesn't fully align below the three-column text

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could solve this problem. There is a three-column text I will be using to describe information on my new site and I want to add a

---

property below of these three-column text. But it aligns below of middle and right columns without fully aligning itself below all of these three columns. Here is HTML code:

```
<hr class="divider1">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="column left">
 <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.?</h2>
 <p> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In ex id ad voluptas corporis eveniet sunt veniam? Reprehenderit delectus est fuga obcaecati molestiae? Sapiente nobis blanditiis,iusto pariatur exercitationem officia? </p>
 </div>
 <div class="column middle">
 <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus eius ipsa dolorem animi eligendi rem. </p>
 </div>
 <div class="column right">
 <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, dolores! Alias nisi totam asperiores quos. </p>
 </div>
 <hr class="divider2>" </div>
```

And here is a picture of how it looks like with minimum amount of CSS:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0FI7.png)

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to the front-end but I want to make a simple website of mine.

Thanks in advance.

I tried the float or margin-top property but these two didn't satisfy me, I don't know if they are correct or not.

Comment: There's a typo in " <hr class="divider2>" </div>".    
use </div>   <hr class="divider2">   and everything will be fine

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Take a moment to review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically how to create a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please edit your question to include the corresponding CSS that you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was placed under two columns, after removing it placing in the end of the div, problem was fixed.